# Server Tomcat using Docker on Windows PC

Tags: docker

I made a webapp in Java and I would like to test the site locally using Docker.

The war file I created works perfectly but to be read correctly it must be inserted inside this path:

```
/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/
```

For these reasons I decided to use this form:

```
https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat
```

In particular I decided to use this Dockerfile:

```
https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/ec2d88f0a3b34292c1693e90bdf786e2545a157e/9.0/jre11-slim/Dockerfile
```

I added this code towards the end:

```
...
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["cd /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/"]
CMD ["mv ROOT ROOT.old"]
CMD ["mkdir ROOT"]
COPY ./esercitazione.1.maven/ /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I used this code at the Windows 10 prompt:

```
D:
cd "D:\DATI\Docker-Tomcat-Win10"
docker build -t tomcat-9-java-11:v2.0 .
docker run -it --rm --name tomcat-9-java-11-container -p 8888:8080 tomcat-9-java-11:v2.0
```

When I enter this link on the browser:

```
http://192.168.99.103:8888/
```

I see this:

```
https://prnt.sc/n2vti1
```

I'm a beginner with both Docker and Tomcat and I need a little help.

Inside this path I put my unzipped .war file:

```
D:\DATI\Docker-Tomcat-Win10\esercitazione.1.maven
```

Thank you

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

**@Shree Tiwari**

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

First of all thank you for your help!

I deleted all the containers and all the images on Docker and used your Dockerfile (I only changed the name of the folder containing the .war files to be tested).

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre8
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m"
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY ./webapps/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I placed the .war file at this address:

```
D:\DATI\Docker-Tomcat-Win10\webapps\esercitazione.1.maven.war
```

I opened the Windows prompt and I typed:

```
D:
cd "D:\DATI\Docker-Tomcat-Win10"
docker build -t tomcat:v1.0 .
docker run -it --rm --name tomcat-container -p 8888:8080 tomcat:v1.0
```

I entered this URL in the browser:

```
http://192.168.99.103:8888/esercitazione.1.maven/
```

then this other:

```
http://192.168.99.103:8888/
```

Unfortunately none of them went well.

The only mistake I encountered when creating the image is this:

"SECURITY WARNING: You are building to Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. Files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories."

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

**@Miq**

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

First of all thank you for your help!

I also tested your code but it doesn't work.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre11-slim
RUN mv webapps/ROOT webapps/ROOT.old && mkdir webapps/ROOT
COPY ./esercitazione.1.maven/ webapps/ROOT/
```

Code:

```
D:
cd "D:\DATI\Docker-Tomcat-Win10"
docker build -t tomcat:v2.0 .
docker run -it --rm --name tomcat-container tomcat:v2.0
```

Browser:

```
http://192.168.99.103:8080/
```

> > **Other tests:**

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre11-slim
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m"
RUN mv webapps/ROOT webapps/ROOT.old && mkdir webapps/ROOT
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/*
COPY ./webapps/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

docker ps -a
docker images
docker stop tomcat-container
docker rmi tomcat:v3.0

D:
cd "D:\DATI\Docker-Tomcat-Win10"
docker build -t tomcat:v3.0 .
docker run -d --name tomcat-container -p 8888:8080 tomcat:v3.0

http://192.168.99.103:8888/
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

> > **Other tests: (8 April 2019)**

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.17-jre11-slim
LABEL Author="Nome Cognome"
EXPOSE 8080
RUN rm -fr /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
COPY ./esercitazione.1.maven.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

> >

```
docker build -t tomcat-eb:v.9.0.17 .
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat-eb:v.9.0.17
```

> >

I'm going here:

```
http://192.168.99.103:8888
```

and the browser sends me here:

```
https://192.168.99.103:8443
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

> > **Other tests: (I choose another image)**

```
FROM tomee:8-jre-8.0.0-M2-webprofile
LABEL Author="Nome Cognome"
EXPOSE 8080
RUN rm -fr /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
COPY ./esercitazione.1.maven.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

> >

```
docker build -t tomcat-eb:v.9.0.17 .
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat-eb:v.9.0.17
```

> >

If I go here:

```
http://192.168.99.103:8888
```

I see Tomcat home, non my webapp.

> > **Is this a problem without a solution?**

Comment: include logs from docker container.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V6GDHNND62/

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XmqDR9n78y/

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zJmYV2cv2S/

Comment: Hello and always thanks for your interest, you are really very kind.
The first link contains the log that I find on the Windows prompt while the other two logs I find on "Kitematic (Alpha)" in the tab for the two containers created relative to the image v3.0. On Virtualbox there are other logs. Let me know if I answered your question. I'm a beginner, I'm not a professional.

Comment: @Miq, Have you found a solution for me?

Comment: From docker perspective it looks fine. However to be sure, run following command and see if you get "it works!": docker run -it --rm -p 8888:80 httpd

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PBcjv379yG/

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/z5F9PhyvJq/

Comment: Second run seemed to be working, have you been able to see it works on the browser?

Comment: I read "It works!" on the browser.

Comment: If I type:
docker run -it --rm -p 8918:80 httpd
the server works on port 8918.
If I stop the container, I delete both the container and the image and type the following command a second time:
docker run -it --rm -p 8918:80 httpd
the server starts working again.

Comment: After 1200 tests I wrote this code:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/r6RQMxqsnp/
As if by magic I saw my site appear on the browser at this address:
http://192.168.99.103:8888
Then I deleted all the containers and all the images to sort and clean, then I recreated the same image and the same container using the same code.
Unfortunately at the end of the procedure I found the same problems. The browser sends me to this address without displaying any page:
https://192.168.99.103:8443/
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/svK7882M5g/
This thing that is happening to me is shocking!

Comment: I installed Linux Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox then I installed Docker and in the end I made a second attempt:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dyj5RXQNdK/
Unfortunately the speech does not change. I write this:
http://localhost:8888/
and the browser sends me here:
https://localhost:8443/
Browser message translated into English:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/V4BGcvfFM2/
Original browser message:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tg7rdGk3kF/
I do not know what to think...

Comment: Container is working, issue is somewhere with your tomcat config, that redirects you to secure port. To your docker command add additional -p 8443:8443 to bypass this.

Comment: Always thank you for your patience and your advice.
I tried to use these two codes but I find the same problem:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/25zVrZ6sj8/
Is it possible that there is some bug in the image of docker? Isn't there another Tomcat image made by some other user that allows me to see my webapp?

Comment: Where should I save my war in this image?
tomee: 8-jre-8.0.0-M2-webprofile
Is there also a ROOT folder?

Comment: I think I understand why tomcat doesn't work.
The first mistake I made was code level, thanks to your help I solved it. I left feedback.
The second error is instead related to the configuration of Windows 10. I believe that Windows prevents the browser from accessing the container.
I tried this guide but I can't solve it:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/FixedMicrosoftEdgeCantSeeOrOpenVirtualBoxhostedLocalWebSites.aspx
Thanks a lot to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem I see here is that you use CMD instead RUN in your dockerfile. CMD is to define a command that will be run when container is ran. With the Dockerfile you have now, only the last one is executed when you start your container and all of those mkdirs, moves, etc. are never executed. As said, you need to use RUN keywords to indicate command that build process should execute and commit as image layer. You probably also do not need the catalina.sh CMD as it might come from the image you base on, but you need to check it on doc page for the base image or take a peek to it's Dockerfile or use `docker history imagename` To see the layers and commands used to create them.

I took a deeper look into this and the base image you use. In addition to the CMD's your problem is that you change the workdir by running `cd` commands. `catalina.sh` exists in `$CATALINA_HOME` dir, which then is marked as workdir in base image. When you change the active directory by executing `cd` it breaks the image runtime.

I'd suggest you try with following dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre11-slim
RUN mv webapps/ROOT webapps/ROOT.old && mkdir webapps/ROOT
COPY ./esercitazione.1.maven/ webapps/ROOT/
```

No need to use `EXPOSE` and `CMD` as they are defined in base image. also, base image defines WORKDIR to $CATALINA_HOME and that's where you will be when executing any following commands (treat `WORKDIR` as `cd` but in docker style).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I corrected the code with this but it doesn't work:
EXPOSE 8080
RUN cd /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ \
 mv ROOT ROOT.old \
 mkdir ROOT
COPY ./esercitazione.1.maven/ /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

Comment: First of all thank you for your help! You are really very kind! I have tested your Dockerfile but it does not work. Your code and that of Shree Tiwari are very beautiful because they are composed of a few lines and therefore they are even more readable.

Comment: I think I understand why tomcat doesn't work.
The first mistake I made was code level, thanks to your help I solved it. I left feedback.
The second error is instead related to the configuration of Windows 10. I believe that Windows prevents the browser from accessing the container.
I tried this guide but I can't solve it:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/FixedMicrosoftEdgeCantSeeOrOpenVirtualBoxhostedLocalWebSites.aspx
Thanks a lot to everyone

Answer (score 0):

First you need to compile your Code to a war file then you can use below Dockerfile

```
FROM tomcat:9-jre8
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m"
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY ./esercitazione.1.maven/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your help!
I have tested your code without success.
I added in my first post all the steps I performed to implement your Dockerfile. Can you see if I commit any distraction?

Comment: Would you explain the meaning of the asterisk, please?

Comment: I think I understand why tomcat doesn't work.
The first mistake I made was code level, thanks to your help I solved it. I left feedback.
The second error is instead related to the configuration of Windows 10. I believe that Windows prevents the browser from accessing the container.
I tried this guide but I can't solve it:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/FixedMicrosoftEdgeCantSeeOrOpenVirtualBoxhostedLocalWebSites.aspx
Thanks a lot to everyone